# How to preserve previous ngbTab content when switching between tabs in ng-bootstrap Angular 2 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap, gojs

I have a UI where I am using `ngb-tabset` and `ngb-tab` to render the following:

[image]

The user enters something above in the form and obtains a graphical visualization under `Graph Navigation` Tab as follows:

[image]

The user could now click on `Semantic Query` tab and obtain information from the child component.

However when the user clicks back on the `Graph Navigation` tab I get the following error:

```
 myDiagram is undefined
```

where `myDiagram` is a `go.Diagram` instance which gets information from the parent component and renders the diagram.([GoJS](https://gojs.net))

### Code

`parent.component.html`

```
<ngb-tabset>
    <ngb-tab title="Graph Navigation">
        <template ngbTabContent>
        <explore-search-details [config]="visData" [lang]="language"></explore-search-details>
        </template>
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab title="Semantic Query">
        <template ngbTabContent>
            <explore-search-semantic></explore-search-semantic>
        </template>
    </ngb-tab>

</ngb-tabset>
```

- `explore-search-details` is a child component which takes `visData` and `language` as input variables from the parent component.
- within the `explore-search-details.component.html` there is a `div` as follows which takes care of rendering

  ```
    <div #myDiagramDiv></div>
  ```

#### Versions

`angular 2.4.0`, `ng-bootstrap 1.0.0-alpha.21`

## Edit

there was a mistake in my addressing `myDiagram` is a `go.Diagram` type variable which is used within `ngOnChanges()` and `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle hook which goes undefined after the tab is switched back.

Comment: cant you save the data in localstorage or a tempVariable before you change the tab?

Comment: try using a state management technique `ngrx-store` how to setup [read it here](https://medium.com/@aravindfz/setting-up-storemodule-in-ngrx-4-0-b7c60732aa64)

Comment: @Hey24sheep `localStorage` sounds like a good idea however canyou describe the logic of passing the data back the to child component i.e. `visData` and `language` when the tab is clicked again

Comment: assuming you could put (click)="checkData(i)" on your tab click then you could make a function in which you check if (!visData) { visData = localStorage.getItem("prevVisData"); } and get the data from localstorage if your visData is undefined.

Comment: @Hey24sheep is it possible to store a JSON in localStorage? the `visData` is a huge Recursive JSON in my case and i am not sure if `localStorage.setItem('prevVisData, this.visData)` would work

Comment: yes, only json is stored in localstorage so yes you could save it like that

Comment: also there seems to be a problem I did not address let me edit the question again

Comment: There is one more issue. visData might be an object currently so you might have to JSON.stringify or angular.toJson it when you save it and parse it when you get it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158873/discussion-between-shan-desai-and-hey24sheep).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<ngb-tabset [destroyOnHide]="false">
```

The default value is `true` which renders the content every time you switch tabs. Reference: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/api

Comment: This saved my day! Rendering huge data again on a single tab switch wasn't a good user experience.

Answer (score 2):

For the first issue, Try to use LocalStorage to preserve tab states.

> there was a mistake in my addressing myDiagram is a go.Diagram type variable which is used within ngOnChanges() and ngAfterViewInit() lifecycle hook which goes undefined after the tab is switched back.

Try putting your reInit code in setTimeout, so you set up your dom elem in the next cycle instead of the current one.